# Fire SendGrid webhooks only for specific categories,

Tags: sendgrid, webhooks

SendGrid's webhooks, once enabled, will fire with every e-mail sent. Or so that seems to be what the documentation implies.

I'm wondering if there's anyway to have the webhooks fire only if certain filters match a pre-defined set. In particular I'm interested in the category filter matching something specific, and only fire webhook when matched, and not fire it by default on all e-mails sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to limit events by category, but you could probably set up a simple filter that would check for the existence of a specific category.

Comment: Just as I thought. Certainly filtering out categories is possible, but if you have a very active mailing list, then you can expect to field a lot of 'useless' webhooks, which is something I'd like to avoid. Looks like that's not possible at this time.